# Rotating file handler for JSON logs in Python

Tags: python, json, logging

I am working on saving the `json` logs using python. Below is the code:

```
log_file = 'app_log.json'

log_json = dict()
log_json["Data"] = {}

log_json['Data']['Key1'] = "value1"
log_json['Data']['alert'] = False
log_json['Data']['Key2'] = "N/A"

log_json['Created'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()

with open(log_file, "a") as f:
    json.dump(log_json, f)#, ensure_ascii=False)
    f.write("\n")
```

Now above code is generating the log file. But I have noticed that the file size is increasing a lot and in future, I might face disk space issue. I was wondering if there is any pre built rotating file handler available for json in which we can mention fixed size lets say `100mb` and upon reaching this size it will delete and recreate the new file.

I have previously used `from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler` to do this in case of `.log` files but also want to do this for `.json` files. Please help. Thanks

Comment: haven't tried it myself, but [this part of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#cookbook-rotator-namer) looks related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not care about the log file name.

You can use [the rotating handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler) which you used for .log file for .json file also.

See sample example below

```
# logging_example.py

import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import time

logfile = os.path.join("/tmp", "demo_logging.json")

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

fh = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile, mode='a', maxBytes=1000, backupCount=5)  # noqa:E501

fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")

fh.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    logger.info("Long string to increase the file size")
```

You can also look at [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) if you are working in Unix environment. It is a great and simple tool with good documentation to do just exactly what you need.

Comment: I am talking about json logging which means it will have a json file which will have a key value pair. In your example, I don't see any key value pair

Comment: That is fine. You can configure your json log message in a key-value pair (python dict) and then use json.dumps which will convert it yo str and log it. 
logger.info(json.dumps(YOUR_JSON_MESSAGE_OBJ))

Answer (score 1):

1. You can implement [structured logging](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#implementing-structured-logging) with `RotatingFileHandler`

```py
import json
import logging
import logging.handlers
from datetime import datetime

class StructuredMessage:
    def __init__(self, message, /, **kwargs):
        self.message = message
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s >>> %s' % (self.message, json.dumps(self.kwargs))

_ = StructuredMessage   # optional, to improve readability

log_json = {}
log_json["Data"] = {}

log_json['Data']['Key1'] = "value1"
log_json['Data']['alert'] = False
log_json['Data']['Key2'] = "N/A"

log_json['Created'] = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()

LOG_FILENAME = 'logging_rotatingfile_example.out'

# Set up a specific logger with our desired output level
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add the log message handler to the logger
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
              LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=20, backupCount=5)
bf = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(bf)

logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.info(_('INFO', **log_json))
```

**Note:** check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#implementing-structured-logging) for more info about `structured-logging-python`

2. you can use also use [json-logging-python](https://github.com/bobbui/json-logging-python) with `RotatingFileHandler`

```py
import logging
import json
import traceback
from datetime import datetime
import copy
import json_logging
import sys

json_logging.ENABLE_JSON_LOGGING = True


def extra(**kw):
    '''Add the required nested props layer'''
    return {'extra': {'props': kw}}


class CustomJSONLog(logging.Formatter):
    """
    Customized logger
    """

    def get_exc_fields(self, record):
        if record.exc_info:
            exc_info = self.format_exception(record.exc_info)
        else:
            exc_info = record.exc_text
        return {'python.exc_info': exc_info}

    @classmethod
    def format_exception(cls, exc_info):
        return ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info)) if exc_info else ''

    def format(self, record):
        json_log_object = {"@timestamp": datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
                           "level": record.levelname,
                           "message": record.getMessage(),
                           "caller": record.filename + '::' + record.funcName
                           }
        json_log_object['data'] = {
            "python.logger_name": record.name,
            "python.module": record.module,
            "python.funcName": record.funcName,
            "python.filename": record.filename,
            "python.lineno": record.lineno,
            "python.thread": record.threadName,
            "python.pid": record.process
        }
        if hasattr(record, 'props'):
            json_log_object['data'].update(record.props)

        if record.exc_info or record.exc_text:
            json_log_object['data'].update(self.get_exc_fields(record))

        return json.dumps(json_log_object)


json_logging.init_non_web(custom_formatter=CustomJSONLog, enable_json=True)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
LOG_FILENAME = 'logging_rotating_json_example.out'

handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
              LOG_FILENAME, maxBytes=20, backupCount=5)

logger.addHandler(handler)

log_json = {}
log_json["Data"] = {}

log_json['Data']['Key1'] = "value1"
log_json['Data']['alert'] = False
log_json['Data']['Key2'] = "N/A"

logger.info('Starting')
logger.debug('Working', extra={"props":log_json})
```

**Note:** check [here](https://github.com/bobbui/json-logging-python) for more info about `json-logging-python`

Answer (score -1):

You can try this just before you write / append to the file. This should check to see if the file has reached the max lines size, then it will remove one line of code from the beginning of the file before you append as usual to the end of the file.

```
filename = 'file.txt'
maxLines = 100

count = len(open(filename).readlines())

if(count > maxLines) {
  with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
    data = fin.read().splitlines(True)
  with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
    fout.writelines(data[1:])
}
```

Comment: Can who ever voted this answer down, comment on why they voted it down?